# How can I condence this function into returning a value from a list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I understand it may not be best practices or conventional but this is more of a personal challenge.

```
def initialize_dataset(source):
    all_features = []
    targets = []
    for (sent, label) in source:
        feature_list=[]
        feature_list.append(avg_number_chars(sent))
        feature_list.append(number_words(sent))
        all_features.append(feature_list)
        targets.append(0) if label=="austen" else targets.append(1)
    return all_features, targets
```

Example of what I'm looking for. I understand that it might not be possible to get it down to one single list and or value. But something close to it. I'd like to kind of expand my thinking on writing list comprehensions.

```
def sample_function(data):
    return [i for i in data ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Success! My gaaaaaaaaaaaaaaawd its ugly!

```
def initialize_dataset(source):
    all_features, targets = [],[]; [(all_features.append([avg_number_chars(sent), number_words(sent)]), targets.append(0) if label == "austen" else targets.append(1)) for (sent, label) in source]; return all_features, targets
```